# How do I allow end user 'blocked sender lists' to work even if the server manages spam filtering?

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010, spam-filter

Client filtering in Outlook 2010 is disabled when the server is managing spam filtering. Unfortunately I have a few high profile users that prefer to spam-block mailing lists rather than unsubscribe, so even though the email is not really spam they are upset that it is coming into their mailbox.

As seen [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/FSENext/thread/1d99bb99-fccd-46c2-95bb-a8881a0b58ff/), I am not the first person to wrestle with this issue, and the suggested fix there (setting `New-FseExtendedOption –Name CFAllowBlockedSenders –Value true`) also failed to work for me.

Can anyone provide another possible fix? Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 1):

First, tell the high-profile users to stop being such crybabies: "Wah! I don't want to see these messages in my inbox but I don't want to take 15 seconds to click unsubscribe!"

Or, next time you are working on their computer, click unsubscribe for them or send an unsubscribe email or whatever it takes.

Or set up a rule in Outlook to auto-delete messages from that address.

But the real answer is to tell them they're being ridiculous.

Comment: This is kind of a grey-zone. As a rule of thumb, sysadmins should always educate users rather than conforming to "ridiculous" wishes. Then again, the "high-profile users" (who sometimes feel the need to cry particularly loud for some reason) might also be the ones with the final say on the IT budget. Keep your friends close and your worst enemies closer

Comment: The culture and balance of IT vs users varies from business to business. This one (a university) has the balance tipped rather far toward the users, and this is an executive. While I would love to recommend that they take care of the mail the proper way, to be perfectly honest filtering out company newsletters is how MOST people deal with the issue. This user is not being unreasonable or abnormal. The 'correct' solution is significantly more inconvenient to accomplish for 100+ lists... hours of work, billable at probably 100+ dollars per hour to the organization. I'd rather fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize [Safelist aggregation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125168.aspx).

You can set the number of allowed blocked and safe senders on a per-mailbox basis with:

```
Set-Mailbox mailuser@domain.tld -MaxSafeSenders 100 -MaxBlockedSenders 500
```

Check out ["Configure Safelist Aggregation"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998280.aspx) on TechNet